# I need help fixing my html and java script code

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a place where you key in your next birthday and the page does a `window.alert` to tell you how many days are left for your birthday. When I run the code, before I key in the birthday, the alert says NaN which means not a number. I want it to work after I key in the birthday after I click submit. This is what I coded:

`

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
    
</form>

<script>
let date_1 = new Date(document.getElementById("bday").value);
let date_2 = new Date();

let difference = date_1.getTime() - date_2.getTime();
let TotalDays = Math.ceil(difference / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
window.alert(TotalDays);

</script>
</body>`
```

Comment: because you need to attach event handlers and wait for the user to be done entering in the value. So you need to either attach click listener to the button or submit listener on the form.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Birthday Countdown</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form onsubmit="calculateDaysLeft(event)">
    <label for="bday">Enter your birthday:</label>
    <input type="date" id="bday" name="bday" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

  <script>
    function calculateDaysLeft(event) {
      event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission to avoid page reload

      // Get the user's birthday from the input field
      let userBirthday = new Date(document.getElementById("bday").value);

      // Get the current date
      let currentDate = new Date();

      // Calculate the difference in milliseconds
      let difference = userBirthday.getTime() - currentDate.getTime();

      // Calculate the difference in days and show the alert
      let totalDays = Math.ceil(difference / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
      window.alert(`There are ${totalDays} days left until your birthday!`);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see basically two problems here.
First of all, the value that you are getting from bday is going to be a string, so you should be sure of the format of that value. You need to get the day, the month and the year, in order to create a string like "day/month/year", to convert it into a date type, using Date.parse().

Secondly, to get the actual date, you should use Date.now(). The constructor alone will not work.

Apllying these changes we have:

```
let date_1 = Date.parse("13/10/2023");
let date_2 = Date.now();

let difference = date_1 - date_2;
let TotalDays = Math.ceil(difference / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
window.alert(TotalDays);
```